# Vuetify expansion panel I'm manually triggering is not animating the first time you trigger it. Works normally after first activation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

NEW INFO: It looks like, based on [their example from the docs](https://codepen.io/barneychampaign/pen/zYKGgGW?editors=101), that their elements aren't animating on initial trigger, either, when opened by manipulating a model. It works fine if you click the header to trigger it, but opening them via a model, on initial page load in Chrome at least, does not animate properly.

---

I have an [expansion panel](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#usage) that I am manually triggering to expand/close. It does work, so when the bound model changes it does indeed expand and close the panel. The weirdness is that it only animates after it's been opened once. On page load, the first time you open it, it opens but has no transition - it just appears. Subsequent open/closes all work fine, and it animates the way it's supposed to.

I feel like it doesn't know the height of the content on the initial animation, or something, so it doesn't do it. That's something I used to have to solve with `scrollheight` and overflows and yada yada back in the day, but since I'm using Vue and Vuetify, I shouldn't have to manually animate this thing.

There are definitely other ways to address this UX that would bypass the need for the expansion panel, but now it's got my curiosity and I would love to know what's happening here. Am I triggering it the wrong way?

You can try it out by running the snippet and clicking "Run" to reset it and simulate initial page load before clicking the "i". You'll see the panel "pop" in instead of animating the first time it opens. Thanks for any insight.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      infoActive: false
    };
  },

  computed: {
    panelOpen() {
      if (this.infoActive) {
        return 0;
      }

      return -1;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  padding: 8px;
}

.example {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.is-active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-container class="example">
    <v-row>
      <v-col align="right">
        Click this i to open the panel ->
        <v-btn icon outlined small color="white" :class="{ 'is-active': infoActive }" @click="infoActive = !infoActive">
          <v-icon :color="infoActive ? 'blue' : 'white'">
            mdi-information-variant
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col align="right">
        <v-expansion-panels v-model="panelOpen" accordian>
          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel.
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-expansion-panels>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  <br>
  <p>On page load, or after clicking "Run" in this snippet, the first time you click that "i" at the top right it doesn't animate the panel opening. It does open, but it doesn't do the transition. Subsequent toggles work fine, with transition. What gives? Why isn't it animating the first time you expand it?<br><br>It takes a split second to show it the first time, so I think it's still "animating" over the proper time...but the height isn't changing. Is it related to it not know the height of the contents correctly or something, so it doesn't know the height to animate?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For future explorers, this is sort of reported already in their github issues, as a performance problem, but it's not. It's due to the content not being there on initial animation, so it doesn't know a height to animate.

The solution? Add the `eager` prop to your `v-expansion-panel-content` component, so the height can be calculated on page load instead of first interaction with the component:

```
<v-expansion-panel-content eager>
  Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel. Contents of the panel.
</v-expansion-panel-content>
```

This has it working correctly - best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. After reading this I was curious and tried making the eager prop dynamic. It turns out that you can set the eager status right before changing the value of the `v-expansion-panels` v-model value and have the animation run. I didn't even need to wait for the nextTick, but I did have to use a separate variable to store the eager state. So in case someone doesn't want to eager load at the start they can use a similar approach. For my use case eager loading on page load was sufficient.